# Why put two different position rules in one css selector

Tags: css

Found this is some example CSS I was reading and I'm having a hard time determining why there are two position rules in one selector.

```
#Div
{
     position:fixed !important;
     position:absolute;
}
```

What does this accomplish?  Isn't the `!important` element always going to override the `position: absolute`?

Comment: It's either a browser hack or someone who doesn't know what they are doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All browsers that support `position:fixed` will use it, the others fall back to `absolute`.

Comment: +1 I would think it would make more sense to switch the two around and lose '!important' though.

Comment: Some browsers may reset the attribute to the user agent default when finding an invalid value. But I'm just guessing :).

Comment: @binarious: As far as I know all browsers will ignore an invalid declaration, rather than falling back to the default value. Either way, both this and what Gary describes will work the same: IE6 applies `position: absolute` while other browsers apply `position: fixed`.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn well then I don't understand why so many articels using the method posted by the OP.

Comment: Because it works? There are many ways to skin a cat. That said, this does exploit two IE6 flaws when only one needs to be exploited (no `fixed` support), the other being that it ignores important declarations in the same rule and always applies the last one.